# $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ is a separable Hilbert space.

Tags: proof-verification, hilbert-spaces

I want to show $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ is separable. My idea is $C_{c}(\mathbb{R})$ is dense in $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ in $L^2$ norm and polynomials with rational coefficients are dense in $C[a,b]$ in $\sup$  norm and hence in $L^2$ norm. Is my idea correct?

Comment: It is basically correct, just is seems to me that you should be more careful in the transition from $C_c$ to polynomials in $C[a,b]$. Probably you can restrict to $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ and the space of functions you are constructing consists of rational polynomials in $[a,b]$ that are zero in $a$ and $b$?